# Не отображается содержимое ListCell в ListView (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

В рамках упражнения "Приложение TODO List" хочу создать такой вот список карточек:

[image]

Класс `TasksListController` берёт данные тасков из `tasksGateway`, приводит их к `ObservableList` и помещает в `tasksListView`:

```java
public class TasksListController {

  private static TasksGateway tasksGateway; // Инициализация опущена чтобы не засорять листинг
  @FXML private ListView<ObservableTask> tasksListView;


  @FXML
  private void initialize() {

    ObservableList<ObservableTask> observableTasks = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Task> pair: TasksListController.tasksGateway.getAll().entrySet()) {
      observableTasks.add(new ObservableTask(pair.getValue()));
    }

    this.tasksListView.setCellFactory(list -> new TasksListController.TaskCell());
    this.tasksListView.setItems(observableTasks);
  }


  private static class TaskCell extends ListCell<ObservableTask> {

    @FXML private Label titleLabel;
    @FXML private Label noteLabel;

    public TaskCell() {
      this.loadFXML();
    }


    private void loadFXML() {
      try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Presenter/Components/TaskList/TaskCard.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
      } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load 'TaskCard.fxml' component:\n" + exception.getMessage());
      }
    }


    @Override
    public void updateItem(ObservableTask observableTask, boolean doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData) {

      super.updateItem(observableTask, doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData);

      if (doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData) {
        return;
      }

      this.titleLabel.setText(observableTask.getTitle());
      if (observableTask.getNote() != null) {
        this.noteLabel.setText(observableTask.getNote());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Всё работает без ошибок, но в списке данные не отображаются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Получение данных из `tasksGateway` я проверил - нет проблем. У меня 4 экземпляра `ObservableTask`; каждый из них выводится в консоль в методе `updateItem` (при `doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData == false`).
- Вывод в консоль `observableTask.getTitle()` и `observableTask.getNote()` также проверил.
- Первые четыре пункта списка выделяются синим при клике - это значит что ячейки в список были добавлены.

FXML-Шаблон компонента `TasksList`:

```
<ListView
  fx:controller="Presenter.Components.TaskList.TasksListController"
  fx:id="tasksListView"
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
/>
```

Если есть смысл его во-что-то оборачивать, то он для меня неочевиден.

FXML-шаблон компонента `TaskCard`:

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
  <children>
    <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" />
    <VBox>
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="titleLabel" style="-fx-font-size: 24px;" text="&lt;TitleHere&gt;">
          <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
          </VBox.margin>
        </Label>
        <Label fx:id="noteLabel" style="-fx-font-size: 14px;" text="&lt;Note here&gt;" wrapText="true" />
      </children>
      <HBox.margin>
        <Insets left="12.0" />
      </HBox.margin>
    </VBox>
  </children>
  <padding>
    <Insets left="12.0" right="12.0" />
  </padding>
</HBox>
```

Так он выглядит в `SceneBuilder`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Быть может, если данные существуют, они просто не добавляются способом на фрейм? Пробовали обернуть this.tasksListView.setItems в Platform run later ?

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, благодарю Вас за комментарий. Нет не пробовал, потому что во-первых я об этом никогда не слышал, а если это необходимо, то я должен понять, по какой причине обычный способ не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в `TaskCell` в методе `updateItem()` нужно добавить вызов `setGraphic()` рутового элемента ячейки, т.е.:

```
private static class TaskCell extends ListCell<ObservableTask> {
  @FXML HBox bBox;

  @Override
  public void updateItem(ObservableTask observableTask, boolean doesNotRepresentAnyDomainData) {
...
    setGraphic(bBox);
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Всё заработало! Но что это таинственный метод и почему его так жизненно важно вызывать при каждом `updateItems`?

Comment: @БоковГлеб так или иначе у списка есть фабрика ячеек, по умолчанию это `javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin` и там также используется `setGraphic()` при вызове `updateItem()`, так что это просто такой механизм работы)

Comment: @БоковГлеб если ответ верный, то примите его как правильный пожалуйста)

Comment: Посмотрел [справку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) по этому методу... "An optional icon for the Labeled" - выглядит как будто совершенно не имеющего ни никакого отношения к списку карточек, но тем не менее, от него зависит отобразится ли содержимое или нет. Странный какой-то метод :)