# Как правильно динамически создавать объекты с определенным стилем в JavaFX?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, intellij-idea, scene-builder

Возник вопрос, у меня есть VBox, хочу туда при инициализации сцены вставлять лейблы из бд.
Как думаю решить это:

1. Создал класс с одноименными переменными(например Cars) и включи туда сеттеры и геттеры.
2. В цикле прошелся по ResultSet и создал arraylist из этих классов и присвоил переменным значения из бд(знаю, что hibernate используют для подобного, но я пока не дотягиваю).

Теперь вопрос, как правильно добавить в Vbox со стилем.
То есть я в конструкторе класса который создал условный Cars, должен программно менять вид и вдобавок подключить файл css к нему, вытягивая стили.

Или же я могу в scene builder ка то сделать данный label, а потом в самом классе наследовать его свойства и создавать новые лейблы, при этом первый лейбл от которого я буду брать стили должен быть не виден на самой сцене, а в scene builder виден.(Если вы поняли про что я)

Подскажите, как более правильно и грамотно это сделать?

Comment: непонятно) вы хотите один fxml унаследовать от другого? или один fxml вставить в другой? или выгрузить fxml из бд?

Comment: Если на пальцах, к примеру есть таблица в бд Cars(id,name), создал класс Cars(с переменными id,name). Из бд прочел все и получил ArrayList<Cars>.
Вот мне надо в VBox вставить label с texy=Cars.name, и для этого label кучу всяких свойств(ширина, цвет, рамки, и т.п).
Как грамотнее сделать это. Просто унаследовать класс Cars от класса Label и в конструкторе перечислить эти свойства(и программно и с css файлом) или же в scene builder вручную закинуть лейбл в vbох, прописать стили, и каким-то образом потом динамически копировать его

Comment: Если у вас ListView, то гляньте вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1259635/5030 но в целом хорошее правило отделять сущность БД от вьюх, так что наследоваться в сущности от вьюхи не желательно). Далее вопрос как создавать Label - программно или через fxml - в целом если это что-то простое, то и проще программно, а если предполагается сложная конструкция как вышеприведенном вопросе - то лучше через fxml

Comment: `Если у вас ListView, то гляньте вопрос ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1259635/5030 но в целом хорошее правило отделять сущность БД от вьюх, так что наследоваться в сущности от вьюхи не желательно).`
То есть, это будет просто класс, в котором я создам в конструкторе Label и изменю его, без наследования.

`public class Cars{
public Cars(){
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.(свойства какие-то)
}
}`

Comment: Добавление `Label` в `VBox` и аналоги `vbox.getChildren(label)`. Перед установкой циклом `Label` советую добавить в `Map`, используя в качестве ключей идентификаторы из базы. Так же их можно добавить в `label.setUserData(id)`. Для последующего использования. Стиль добавляется `label.getStyleClass().add("carstyle")`. Второй вариант это создание кастомного label, куда конструктором передается машина и внутри настраиваются стили, обработка и прочее. Это посложнее, но более структурированно.